# Pictures slide showing in the background of my vs studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Can anyone tell me what's going on my VS 2017? There are pictures in the background and are doing some slide shows whenever I view the code.

The pictures are from my Pictures folder so I am wondering how the VS background is like that since the vs save files reside on source.

I already tried cleaning using cCleaner but still it occurs.

Here is a screen shot of VS showing an unwanted picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I removed the two other screen shots, there is no point in putting so many pictures into your question. Keep in mind: when asking questions here, it is about describing the problem good enough to receive helpful answers. Redundant information doesn't help, especially when talking about large screen shots.